# execute a batch file when a new file is created in specific folder on win 7

Tags: java, php, windows, batch-file

Let me first describe where I am. For readability, that will take three paragraphs.

**Original Problem:** I am working on a php website, one function of which is to read data from a Word file users upload and then insert the entry into some database. Note: the server is running windows (devil windows!).

**My Solution:** Write a java program to do the word file reading and database inserting stuff, using java Apache POI library. Then execute the java program in one bat file. Then new problem occurs...

**New Problem:** How can we make a specific bat file run on a specific file system event? In my case, the event will be file creation in one assigned folder.

Wish I have made myself totally understood. Waiting for your help. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would implement some kind of **scheduled task**(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx) on the server that runs the Java app you have for adding the files. Depending on your traffic, you could set it to run every 5 minutes, or every 5 hours, or whatever.

That Java app would then do this:

1. Look at that directory
2. If it sees some file(s), loads the file(s) into the database
3. When it is finished loading the files, it would delete them from the directory (so it doesn't add them the next time the task executes).

**At the same time,** I'm surprised you're not implementing something with PHP through the web app. If your website is already in php, wouldn't it make sense to keep this application logic as part of the PHP stuff as well? To each their own.

If you went the **php route**, a super simple approach would be this:

- have some page `submit_doc.php` with a form where users can upload a doc
- when they hit the submit button, some other php file would execute, say `upload_doc.php`
- `upload_doc.php` would handle connecting to the db and adding the file to the db

Comment: Your solution sounds wonderful to me! Your second suggestion is just what I think of at first, but I am such a php newbie that I even can't figure out where to start. Can you explain the php method more in detail?

Comment: one of the nice things about php is that it's extremely beginner-friendly. Assuming you already have the database set up to store these files, it'd be pretty straight forward to write php code that inserts a file to the db. Here's a small tutorial about connecting to a (mysql) database and running SQL http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm. If you just look up how to connect/insert to a database with php, there are many tutorials/articles.

Comment: Maybe I haven't made it clear. The website users can upload some word files, each corresponding to one database entry. But we have to extract those data items from those files, then insert them into the database table. Directly inserting entire file into database doesn't make sense here. I don't know any php library or something similar can read word file directly. If there are some such tools, my headache will be alleviated a lot.

Comment: Okey, that's another wonderful alternative approach. Thank you a lot, dear guy!